# Sequence : $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=3n$

Tags: number-theory, functional-equations

Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$  such that $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=3n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ ?

My attempt :

Substitute $n=1$, $f(f(1))+f(2)=3$ so $f(2) \in \{1$ or $2\}$

If $f(2)=1, f(f(1))=2$

Substitute $n=2$, $f(f(2))+f(3)=6$ so $f(1)+f(3)=6$

Substitute $n=3$, $f(f(3))+f(4)=9$

If $f(2)=2$, $f(f(1))=1$ so $f(1)\not= 2$

Comment: I'm confused as to where you get these equivalents I guess.

Comment: May be, the next question could be $f(f(n))+f(n+1)=4n$

Comment: How do you get $f(3)=6$?

Comment: @ Roddy MacPhee, I've added the detail.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici, There is no more question :)

Comment: I was just kidding you ! Cheers.

Comment: @carat When you say substitute $n=3$, $f(f(3))+f(4)=9$ you jump to "so $f(6)+f(4)=9$" which implies that $f(3)=6$.

Comment: @kingW3. Edited. Thank you.

Comment: The answers below seem to suggest there is no such function. Of course, we head off next to $4n$.

Comment: @ астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг. We shouldn't, some answerer have already prepared the solution for $4n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I claim that no such functions exist.

First, suppose $f(2)=2$. We get
$$f(f(2))+f(3)=6\Longrightarrow f(3)=4.$$
We get a contradiction, since
$$2f(4)=f(f(3))+f(4)=9.$$

Hence $f(2)=1$. As you said, $f(f(1))=2$, and in particular $f(1)\neq 2$. Let's go through all the cases of $f(1)$ (since $f(1)+f(3)=6$, there are only 5 cases):

- $f(1)=1$; then $2=f(f(1))=f(1)=1$, a contradiction.
- $f(1)=2$ was already ruled out.
- $f(1)=3$; then $f(3)=3$. But also $f(3)=f(f(1))=2$, a contradiction.
- $f(1)=4$; then $f(4)=f(f(1))=2$ and $f(3)=2$. We get a contradiction, since $9=f(f(3))+f(4)=f(2)+f(4)=4$.
- $f(1)=5$; then $f(5)=f(f(1))=2$ and $f(3)=1$. Hence $$9=f(f(3))+f(4)=f(1)+f(4)=5+f(4),$$ implying $f(4)=4$. This does not work with $f(f(4))+f(5)=12$.

As a conclusion, there are no such functions.

Answer (score 2):

We will show that there is no such function.

Since $f(2)+ff(1)=3$, we have two case:

---

$f(2)=2$:

$ff(2)+f(3)=6\implies f(3)=4$

$ff(3)+f(4)=9\implies 2f(4)=9$.

The last one is impossible hence $f(2)=1$.

---

$f(2)=1:$

$$
ff(2)+f(3)=6\implies f(3)=6-f(1)\\
ff(3)+f(4)=9\implies f(6-f(1))+f(4)=9.
$$ 
First of all $f(1)\neq 1,2$.

If $f(1)=5$ then :
$$
ff(1)=2\implies f(5)=2\\
f(3)=1\implies f(4)=4\\
ff(4)+f(5)=4+f(5)=4+2\neq 3\times 4.
$$
So $f(1)\neq 5$.

If $f(1)=3$:
$$
ff(1)=f(3)=2\\
f(3)=6-f(1)=3
$$
So again $f(1)\neq 3$.

If $f(1)=4$ then $f(3)=2$:
$$
f(f(1))=f(4)=2\\
ff(3)+f(4)=9\implies 1+f(4)=9.
$$
So $f(1)\neq 4$.

Therefore there is no function satisfying this condition.